# How can I find MariaDB URL to be used with Keycloak?

Tags: mariadb, keycloak

I was using Keycloak 16. Now that I want to upgrade to Keycloak 20, I see that they have changed a lot.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file from 16:

```
version: "3.9"
services: 
    accounts:
        image: jboss/keycloak:latest
        container_name: Accounts
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
        environment: 
            - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://accounts.example.local/auth
            - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
            - KEYCLOAK_USER=user
            - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=pass
            - DB_VENDOR=mariadb
            - DB_ADDR=database
            - DB_DATABASE=accounts
            - DB_USER=db_user
            - DB_PASSWORD=db_pass
        logging:
            driver: none
        restart: always
    database:
        image: mariadb
        container_name: AccountsDatabase
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        environment:
            - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=root_pass
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=accounts
            - MYSQL_USER=db_user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=db_pass
        volumes:
            - /Temp/AccountsDatabases:/var/lib/mysql 
        logging:
            driver: none
        restart: always
    admin:
        image: adminer
        container_name: AccountsAdminer
        restart: always
        logging:
            driver: none
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        environment:
            - ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER=database
```

Now [it seems](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers) that Keycloak needs a database URL.

I can't find out how can I connect MariaDB to Keycloak. I can't find out the URL of my MariaDB URL and [the Keycloak blog](https://www.keycloak.org/2022/02/dbs.html) says that they won't provide examples for any database other than their first class PostreSQL.

I'm stuck at this point. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Their documents show [KC_DB_URL](https://www.keycloak.org/server/containers) is a JDBC URL.

So the simple form of `jdbc:mariadb://host/database` seems used in [their tests](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/fb315b57c3c308d5d5e6646b8cce1f86abf1d523/docs/tests-db.md), so for you:

```
     environment: 
        - KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL=https://accounts.example.local/auth
        - PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true
        - KEYCLOAK_USER=user
        - KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=pass
        - KB_DB_URL=jdbc:mariadb://database/accounts
        - KB_DB_USER=db_user
        - KB_DB_PASSWORD=db_pass
```

note: I'm hoping/assuming the JDBC driver for MariaDB is in their container which it may not be.